# How to integrate reckon account API?

Tags: crm, quickbooks, zoho

I want to integrated Zoho CRM with Reckon application,
firstly i am trying to integrated Reckon Accounts Hosted and read out Docs and they provide some FTP details and forcing to implement first Reckon Accounts Desktop API.
also i am using Ubuntu 16.04 so is it possible to integrated this on linux machine and does anyhave idea to implement API of Reckon Step by stp.
Thanks.

[Reckon api](https://reckonproduction.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. The first step is to learn how to write the XML used by the desktop version - and it is also used with Hosted. The destop version used the qbxmlrp2.dll - Hosted connects initially through the API, but then you embed the xml in post requests that are passed through the qbxmlrp2.dll. Reckon use Version 6.1 of the QuickBooks SDK which is now quite a few versions behind the American SDK. We found the Intuit documentation for the SDK to be quite thorough, but as of may 2017 the Reckon Hosted documentation is not overly helpful and leaves a lot to be figured out.